# phpdoc via PEAR under cygwin

Tags: pear, phpdoc

I've installed PEAR and PHPDoc under Cygwin 64 bit.
When running phpdoc I get the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   JMS\Serializer\simplexml_load_string() in
>   /usr/share/pear/phpDocumentor/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/XmlDeserializationVisitor.php:76

I'm running

> PHP 7.1.13 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2018 17:08:03) ( NTS )

with the modules:

```
php-PEAR                  1.10.5-1            OK 
php-xmlrpc                7.1.13-1            OK
```

and installed phpDocumentor-2.9.0.tgz (16,175,113 bytes) using:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org 
pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor
```

Can anyone give a hint of what's missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a bug in that `jms/serializer` package, because the error indicates that the `simplexml_load_string()` function is namespaced inside `JMS\Serializer`, when it's actually a global function from PHP itself (http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).